# How can I fix this query to return all rows which from the original join and all rows using the id in another attribute

Tags: sql, database, self-join

I'm writing a query to return all requirements which are covered by a test case.

Because of the way the requirements are linked, the requirement table also includes a reference to a parent requirement.

My issue is that I'm unsure how to join my tables to return all requirements which are directly covered by a test case, as well as all of their parent requirements.

I've tried to set up a self join on the parent attribute to the requirement id attribute, but for some reason I can't get it to work, and its returning an error ("RQ1"."REQ_FATHER_ID": Invalid Identifier) when I try to reference the parent ID of the table.

Here is what I have working so far, this returns all requirements which are covered directly by a test:

```
SELECT
      R.RQ_USER_34
      /* Requirement ID */, 
      T.TS_NAME
      /* Test Name */,
      T.TS_TEST_ID
      /* Test ID */,
      TC.TC_STATUS
      /* Test Result */,
      TC.TC_TESTCYCL_ID
      /* Test Cycle ID */
    FROM
      TEST  T
      LEFT JOIN TESTCYCL TC ON T.TS_TEST_ID = TC.TC_TESTCYCL_ID
      LEFT JOIN REQ_COVER RC ON T.TS_TEST_ID = RC.RC_ENTITY_ID
      LEFT JOIN REQ R ON R.RQ_REQ_ID = RC.RC_REQ_ID
    ORDER BY
      T.TS_TEST_ID
      ASC
```

Here is the self join I attempted to add the rows from the requirement table which reference the parent id of the above query, and is not working (note that an RQ_FATHER_ID = -1 indicates the requirement has no parent):

```
SELECT
      R1.RQ_USER_34 AS ChildReq,
      R2.RQ_USER_34 AS ParentReq,
      T.TS_NAME,
      T.TS_TEST_ID,
      TC.TC_STATUS,
      TC.TC_TESTCYCL_ID
    FROM
      TEST T
      LEFT JOIN TESTCYCL TC ON T.TS_TEST_ID = TC.TC_TESTCYCL_ID
      LEFT JOIN REQ_COVER RC ON T.TS_TEST_ID = RC.RC_ENTITY_ID
      LEFT JOIN REQ R1 ON R1.RQ_REQ_ID = RC.RC_REQ_ID
      LEFT JOIN REQ R2 ON R2.RQ_REQ_ID = R1.RQ_FATHER_ID
     WHERE
      R1.RQ_REQ_FATHER <> -1
    ORDER BY
      T.TS_TEST_ID
      ASC
```

Comment: From your description it seems like the condition should be `R1.RQ_FATHER_ID <> -1` and it likely belongs in the last ON clause rather than in a WHERE clause